# Dynamically changing background color in VC

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I am stuck with this piece of my homework.
 Maybe someone can explain me how to solve it.

"VC contains a controller with a built-in controller. Both the parent and child controller have three buttons: Green, Yellow, Violet. When you click on one of the buttons in the parent controller, the background color of the child controller changes to the appropriate one. When you click on the button in the child, the background of the parent changes."

Here is what I made in my code

**Parent VC**

```
import UIKit

class OrangeViewController: UIViewController, VioletControllerDelegate {
   
    

    var delegate: VioletControllerDelegate?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            let vcV = segue.destination as! VioletViewController
            vcV.bgColor = view.backgroundColor
            vcV.delegate = self
        }

    
    @IBAction func greenOButton(_ sender: Any) {
        //TO DO
    }
    
    @IBAction func yellowOButton(_ sender: Any) {
        //TO DO
    }
    
    @IBAction func purpleOButton(_ sender: Any) {
        //TO DO
    }
    
    func setColor(color: String) {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: color)
    }
}
```

**Child VC**

```
import UIKit
protocol VioletControllerDelegate{
    func setColor ( color : String)
}

class VioletViewController: UIViewController {
    var bgColor : UIColor?
   
    var delegate: VioletControllerDelegate?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var bgColor = view.backgroundColor
    }
    
    @IBAction func setGreen(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.setColor( color: "green")
    }
    @IBAction func setYellow(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.setColor( color: "yellow")
    }
    
    @IBAction func setViolet(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.setColor( color: "violet")
    }
    
    func setColor ( color : String){
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: color)
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did it. In case someone will need something like this I am posting my answer:

**Parent VC**

```
import UIKit

class OrangeViewController: UIViewController, VioletControllerDelegate {
   
   
    

    var childVC: VioletViewController?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            let vcV = segue.destination as! VioletViewController
            self.childVC = vcV
            vcV.delegate = self
        }

    
    @IBAction func greenOButton(_ sender: Any) {
        childVC?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }
    
    @IBAction func yellowOButton(_ sender: Any) {
        childVC?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }
    
    @IBAction func purpleOButton(_ sender: Any) {
        childVC?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    }
    
    func setColor( color : UIColor) {
        view.backgroundColor = color
    }
}
```

**Child VC**

```
import UIKit
protocol VioletControllerDelegate{
    func setColor ( color : UIColor)
}

class VioletViewController: UIViewController {
    
   
    var delegate: VioletControllerDelegate?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func setGreen(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.setColor( color: UIColor.green)
    }
    @IBAction func setYellow(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.setColor( color: UIColor.yellow)
    }
    
    @IBAction func setViolet(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.setColor( color: UIColor.purple)
    }
    
    
}
```